# How do I scale text with viewport size using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the text size on my landing page to scale linearly with the viewport size. If you look at my site at http://alexanderwhill.com/site2/ you will see what I'm saying. I would like the font size to scale fluidly instead of overflowing.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Not with standard css. you'd need some JS to detect if/when text wraps and dynamically adjust font size

Comment: [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) would handle this well, though it would require implementing a new framework...

Answer (score 0):

That is what [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) are for.

Simple example: http://jsbin.com/ivodam/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

use % for fluidity in css

```
  #maincontent h1 {
    font-size: 50%; /* your desired % */
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 260px;
 }
```

or you can use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), where you would need to specify/know the range of viewport dimensions.